# Can I paint a deck when wet weather is forecasted?

Tags: cleaning, paint, deck

I am planning on painting my mothers deck and I have a limited amount of time.  I am planning on painting it on Saturday, but I saw there is forecast for rain.  I am wondering if it would be better to paint before or after the rain.  I could possibly paint it on Friday or Monday, but with the sanding and priming I have to do, I can't really do much earlier and my mom comes back on Tuesday.  I'm planning on power washing too, probably Wednesday morning because it's supposed to be pretty warm that day, so it would dry well.

Answer (score 2):

I would paint after the rain and make sure there is a tarp over the deck before it rains.  You need the manufacturer's guidelines but two simple rules to painting outside is not touching a damp surface - and it can take a few days for a deck to dry out and not painting within 48 hours of rain forecast.  At 24 hours after painting you could tarp the deck but really better to have a few clear days.  If rain is constant then you just need to wait.

Answer (score 0):

wheather has great influence on painting, if you have to paint on a rainy day, then you must keep your room dry to protect the painting.